# What are the "applications" of quantum optimal transport?

Tags: reference-request, optimal-transportation

A quantum version of the Monge-Kantorovich optimal transport problem aims at optimizing a Hermitian cost matrix $C$ over the set of all bipartite coupling states $\rho_{AB}$, s.t. both of its reduced density matrices $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ are fixed. I'm interested in its "applications". The classical optimal transport theory can be either used as theoretical tools to study important problems arising in PDE (Schrödinger equation/e Boltzmann equation), metric geometry, random matrices, etc., or used to study problems in practice, e.g. urban planning, economics, data science, etc. So I wish to know whether the quantum optimal transport has similar relevance, from both theoretical and practical perspective.

Any answer, references (survey summarizing its development) and comments are highly appreciated.

PS : Thanks for GJC's comment. I've found some related articles :

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.06922.pdf

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.01829.pdf

while I still look for such a summary of this field.

Comment: Some applications are discussed in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.09817.pdf and I'm also interested in this topic. A summary on the related literature is much appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, there are several notions of quantum optimal transports! about the applications I know are the mean-field and semiclassical limits (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.06143.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.04544.pdf, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.12944.pdf), obtaining asymptotic behaviors https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.5377.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This paper by De Palma et. al.
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9420734
provides a series of possible applications in the Future perspective section:

- Quantum State Estimation
- Robustness of Quantum Machine Learning
- Quantum Generative Adversarial Networks
- Quantum Rate Distortion Theory
- Quantum Differential Privacy
- Mixing time of Quantum Markov Semigroups
- Shallow Quantum Circuits
- Quantum Many-Body Hamiltonians

Also in their other paper
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00023-021-01042-3
implicitly mentioned some of the applications referring to its citations [4-9]:

- "the study of partial differential equations, by interpreting many evolution equations as gradient flows with respect to transport-induced metrics [4];
- geometric analysis, with quantitative isoperimetric inequalities [5] and
  synthetic notions of Ricci curvature bounds [6,7];
- stochastic analysis in infinite dimensions [8];
- random combinatorial optimization problems [9];
- statistics and machine learning [10]."

Although in this second paper none of them are specific applications of the *quantum optimal transport* but their claim is that it will be a useful tool to address the quantum version of the above problems.

There is also the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.09817 by Ikeda which provides applications for its quantum optimal transport problem by transforming some of these quantum problems into quantum optimal transport:

- Costly Quantum Walk
- Quantum Cellular Auto
- Automata and Games
- Repeated Quantum Games

I just listed the above items as mentioned in papers. Please look into it further yourself for proper evaluation. Hope it helps.